# Set varaible in after_action callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Is it possible to set an instance variable in an after_action callback? Becouse I can't find a way to make this work...

Controller

```rb
[...]
after_action :set_var
[...]
private
def set_var
  @myvar = "something"
end
[...]
```

But in my view `@myvar` is always nil.
If I change `after_action` with `before_action` it works, but i really need to set this variable after the action gets executed.

Comment: Why do you need to set it after action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of searching I found this:
https://gist.github.com/pietromoro/f13e5ee07537cec649d41b6827a03f99
which actually solved my needs. It is awesome, it creates a new callback for controlles and let me write `before_render :set_var` and even use the same syntax we're all used to (only, except, ...)

Answer (score 2):

As part of the action your views get rendered, so `after_action` is too late for what you're trying to do as the rendering is already done.

What you could try is adjusting the `render` method in your `ApplicationController`

```
private
  def render(*arguments)
    set_var
    super(*arguments)
  end
  def set_var
    @my_var = 'something'
  end
end
```

I haven't tried this.  You'll want to check that it does work for both explicit and implicit renders.
......

Comment: That this is possible, does not mean we should offer it as a "solution", right? Without more information I would strongly advice against this (I mean: just use `before_action`).

Comment: Except `before_action` doesn't meet OP's requirements.  He appears to want to set an instance variable based on some conditions set during the current action.

Answer (score 1):

You can't to pass instance variable to the view after action because controller have rendered the view and all instance variables have yet [assigned there](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/base.rb#L203-L205)

So you need to pass instance variable inside the action or before it.

I don't think you really need monkey patch `ActionController` method.

Most likely the problem can be solved in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `#render` method in application controller.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def render(*args)
    # do stuff here
    super
  end
end
```

`after_action` callback called after render method executed so it won't work for you.